# How to expand Rowwidget by default

Tags: extjs

As a last ditch effort, I am asking here.

I made a grid similar to the one in kitchen sink https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/examples/kitchensink/#row-widget-grid

However, no matter what I try I am not able to get the grid expanded by default.

How to achieve this ?

I tried overriding the row-expander code and expanding each row individually. Though it works, it takes a lot of time. Around 15 mins for 100 - 200 rows

Answer (score 0):

I would wait for the grid to load the data, the view has to be ready as well, once you get there, you can try out the following piece of code, maybe inside your `ViewController`:

```
var grid = this.getView();
var view = grid.getView();
var rowWidget = grid.getPlugin('rowwidget');
if (!grid.rendered || !rowWidget) {
    return;
}
var data = grid.getStore().getRange();
// if for some reason this doesn't work, try waiting until the grid is completely rendered (when you see it)
data.forEach(function(record){
    rowWidget.toggleRow(view.getRow(record), record);
});
```